# Does SPARQL's BIND year function work for xsd:datetimestamp?

Tags: sparql

So I am able to use this query:

```
SELECT ?year
WHERE {    
?timeInt :hasStartTime ?StartT . 
    BIND(year(?StartT) AS ?year) 
}
```

to get an output of 2022. This is my RDF data (in turtle language):

```
:Interval1 :hasStartTime "2022-03-11"^^xsd:date .
```

but when I use this:

```
:Interval1 :hasStopTime "2022-03-11T21:01:23Z"^^xsd:dateTimeStamp .
```

I cannot get my query to output anything. So does this mean that the way BIND works for xsd:date is not the same for xsd:datetimestamp or am I missing something? Are there other options to be able to use the BIND to select for more specific times in xsd:datetimestamp and not just year? Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out. I can use xsd:dateTime (I only changed the xsd:dateTimeStamp to xsd:dateTime) and I am able to get my output of 2022. I can also use hours, minutes, and seconds with bind to find these as well.

Comment: It will depend on whether engine supports that datatype. Some do, some don't. It is not required by the SPARQL spec. xsd:dateTime is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on whether engine supports that datatype. Some do, some don't. It is not required by the SPARQL spec. xsd:dateTime is required.

If necessary you can cast. The most portable way is to write

`strdt(str("2022-03-11T21:01:23Z"^^xsd:dateTimeStamp), xsd:dateTime)`

which does not rely on anything more than the basic spec.